# jQuery asynchronous request with function

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, .post

```
function form(elem) {
    var dati = $(elem).serialize();
    var action = $(elem).attr("action");
    var result = "";
    $.post(action, dati, function (data) {
        result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(result)
        return result;
    });
}
$(document).on("submit", "#new-search-field", function () {
    var data = form($(this));
    alert(data);
    if (......) {.....
    }
});
```

I need to read the asynchronous result from post request but i can't because i get alert(data) before "return result;"

How can i solve it?

Comment: return $.post() (promise) from `form` function and then use relative method to promise, as done() e.g  Please read it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a callback for your post, since with they way your code is now, it calls the post, but then just continues to execute the next command.  I would just add an extra parameter to your function.  Something like this:

```
function form(elem, callback) {
    var dati = $(elem).serialize();
    var action = $(elem).attr("action");
    var result = "";
    $.post(action, dati, function (data) {
        result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        callback(result);
    });
}
$(document).on("submit", "#new-search-field", function () {
    form($(this), function (data) { alert(data); });
    if (......) {.....
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is not how asynchronicity works.

You get the `alert(data)` before `return result;` because `$.post` works asynchronously. The `form` function executes and returns, and then some time later `$.post` will have the Ajax response data available and will call the provided callback function passing the data as an argument.

To accomplish what you want you basically have two options:

- You can either use a callback (that will get called once the asynchronous action completes).
- Use promises/deferreds.

**Callback version 1**:

```
function form(elem, callback) {
    ...
    $.post(..., function(data) {
        data = f(data); // transform data somehow if you have to
        callback(data);
    });
}
$(document).on(..., function() {
    form($(this), function(data) {
        // use data
    });
});
```

**Callback version 2**:

```
function form(elem, callback) {
    ...
    $.post(..., callback);
}
$(document).on(..., function() {
    form($(this), function(data) {
        // use data
    });
});
```

**Promises version**:

```
function form(elem) {
    ...
    return $.post(...);
}
$(document).on(..., function() {
    form($(this))
        .done(function(data) {
           // use data
        })
        .fail(function() {
           // error
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because your post is implemented asynchronous.  try to use a callback function to access the result of your post request